# Programming error 1064

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-error-1064, tornado

When I was trying to use the following SQL to fetch some result from MySQL database,

```
entries = db.query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT %s", count)
```

I got this error:

> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
>   raise errorclass, errorvalue
>   ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20'' at line 1")

I really don't know what's wrong with my SQL script. Actually, it worked pretty well in my previous PHP version of the server. Why it doesn't work in my Python version? Has it anything specific related to the Tornado database wrapper?

I tried to search the whole Internet, no luck. :(

Comment: count = 20 in this context. the error message actually got its value as 20.

Comment: This works for me (Python 2.7, Tornado 2.3, MySQLdb 1.2.3)

Comment: python 2.7.3, Tornado 2.3, MySQLdb 1.2.3

Answer (score 2):

<del>You're using '%s' placeholder, so `count` value (which is obviously 20) gets quoted (which makes your query end with `LIMIT '20'`). Try using `'%d'` instead.</del>

Well, as Cole Maclean said, you can't use non-'%s' placeholders here; that makes my solution a bit wrong, to say the least.

Yet the reason is still the same: LIMIT parameter should be a number, not 'numeric string'. But the quotation marks somehow reach the final query: MySQL error message is clearly about LIMIT '20' line.

That, in turn, may be caused by either a bug in MySQLdb library, or - perhaps - wrong value given to `count` variable: string `'20'` (with quotation marks as part of it) instead of number 20. I admit, both cases seem unlikely to me.

Can you test this query with hard-coded literal in place of `count`? Like...

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT %s", 20)
```

Comment: While %d would be logical, MySQLdb only works with %s placeholders.

Comment: @ColeMaclean Updated the answer. I'm a bit confused about it, as the error message points to LIMIT problem here.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you're right about count actually being "'20'".

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! I modified my method to remove "count" argument. just put 20 there in the method body query. it went through without any error. This is really strange. I checked many other places it says only %s is allowed for db query, %d is not used in such context.

Comment: Check where you are setting count. Make you have it as count = 20 or something like that. Not count = '20' That is likely the issue